# Add a domain alias to a secondary domain using the Google Apps Domains API

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I'm using Google Apps and I'm trying to add a domain alias to a secondary domain I own.

According to this [Google Apps blog article](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2015/10/google-apps-new-domain-management.html)  "the [domains] API lets you programmatically add aliases for any domain, primary or secondary, but aliases for secondary domain can only be added via the API."

I tried the API on [the APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domains/insert) (at the bottom of the page) but only managed to add a domain alias to my primary domain and not to my secondary.

Using a POST method I've tried:

```
{
 "domainName": "alias.domain.com",
 "domainAliases": [
  {
   "parentDomainName": "secondary.domain.com",
   "verified": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Any light on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Jo

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: I'm getting a 200 OK

Comment: and then {

 "kind": "admin#directory#domain",
 "etag": "\"string of results\"",
 "domainName": "alias.domain.com",
 "isPrimary": false,
 "verified": false,
 "creationTime": "1452696452927"
}

Comment: I guess your request should look more like this: `{
  "domainName": "myprimaryappsdomain.com",
  "domainAliases": 
  [
    {
      "parentDomainName": "secondary.somedomain.com",
      "domainAliasName": "aliastosecondarysomedomain.com"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: I tried this request but it provides a 409 error

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "duplicate",
    "message": "Domain is already set up."
   }
  ],
  "code": 409,
  "message": "Domain is already set up."
 }
}

Comment: Thanks for the help btw Konqi, I think the primary domain shouldn't be repeated as it's already taken into account in "my_customer" which is why I receive the 409 Error

Comment: Not sure about the primary domain and the customer. I've seen Google APIs where it's forbidden to give too much information and some where redundant information must be provided. There is no (rational) constant there imho. Sadly I cannot help more than that without actually performing these operations. You could try to list your aliases, see what the output is. Maybe you created the alias during one of your previous attempts and haven't realized it yet.

Comment: Yes - my first thought was to go check if the domain alias had been added previously, but no :( . I'll have to play around some more but I tried many combinations before without success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the DomainAliases API:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domainAliases/insert

From there enter:

```
customer = your immutable ID
domainAliasName = the alias to add
parentDomainName = the secondary domain to which you want to add an alias
```

That should be it.